# How to iterate my child widget in flutter according to the data length?

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, flutter-layout, flutter-listview

I was make the horizontal scroll view but , I want to make my widget iterative and get the data from list so when , I add images from backend the images view accordingly without disturbing the style....

The code for refence below,

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final brand = Provider.of<brandstate>(context).brands;
if (!_isLoding)
  return went_wrong();
else
  return Column(
    children: [
      Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            horizontal: getProportionateScreenWidth(20)),
        child: SectionTitle(
          title: "Special for you",
          press: () {},
        ),
      ),
      SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        child: Row(children: [
          
          SpecialOfferCard(
              image: brand[0].brandimage.toString(), press: () {}),
          SpecialOfferCard(
              image: brand[0].brandimage.toString(), press: () {}),
          SpecialOfferCard(
              image: brand[0].brandimage.toString(), press: () {}),
           
          
         ]),
      ),
    ],
  );
}
}

class SpecialOfferCard extends StatelessWidget {
  const SpecialOfferCard({
    Key? key,
    required this.image,
    required this.press,
  }) : super(key: key);

   final String image;
   final GestureTapCallback press;

       @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Padding(
  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: getProportionateScreenWidth(20)),
  child: GestureDetector(
    onTap: press,
    child: SizedBox(
      width: getProportionateScreenWidth(242),
      height: getProportionateScreenWidth(100),
      child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Image.network(
              "http://10.0.2.2:8000$image",
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                  begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                  end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  colors: [
                    Color(0xFF343434).withOpacity(0.4),
                    Color(0xFF343434).withOpacity(0.15),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                horizontal: getProportionateScreenWidth(15.0),
                vertical: getProportionateScreenWidth(10),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ListView.builder` widget

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: brand.length,
  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
  itemBuilder: (context,index){
    return SpecialOfferCard(
        image: brand[index].brandimage.toString(), 
        press: () {});}),
```